How to change color of box-shadow into "blur" of Inverted corners in CSS
I made L shaped menu bar with inverted corners inside by this method:Inverted corners, but the problem is I cannot change the corner color to blur because its color is from box-shadow.
My question is how can I change it to color: none; blur: 20px, like rec3 and rec4? Or is there any  other way to make L shaped menu bar?
Problem:

This is my code


body {
  background-image: url(https://images.pexels.com/photos/33109/fall-autumn-red-season.jpg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=1260&h=750&dpr=1);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}

.rec3 {
  /*Horizontal bar*/
  position: fixed;
  width: 60vw;
  height: 80px;
  backdrop-filter: blur(20px);
  bottom: 20px;
  left: 20px;
  border-radius: 0 25px 25px 80px;
}

.rec4 {
  /*Vertical bar*/
  position: fixed;
  width: 80px;
  height: 60vh;
  bottom: 90px;
  left: 20px;
  backdrop-filter: blur(20px);
  border-radius: 25px 25px 0 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  z-index: -1;
}

#top {
  position: absolute;
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  left: 80px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#top {
  top: -30px;
}

#top::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  height: 200%;
  width: 200%;
  border-radius: 100%;
  box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px 100px blue;
  /*How can i change this color like rec3 and rec 4 bar*/
  z-index: -1;
}

#top::before {
  top: -100%;
  right: -100%;
}
<div class="rec3">
  <div id="top"></div>
</div>
<div class="rec4">
</div>



I tried to make an SVG with AI but I don't know how to do it.
AdobeIllus

Your posted code doesn't really reproduce your problem, could you add enough content (background image, relevant icons...) in order that we can reproduce the problem, and then easily see what's going on?

Please attach pictures of the background and icons, (you can attach them online), so that we can reproduce the problem and understand where the problem is

@DavidThomas it's that corner piece (#top::before{box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px 100px gray;}) that needs to behave like the .rec3 and .rec4.

I have updated the background image, icons are just 60px 60px png and it doesn't effect any thing.

Icons img are png file on my computer, so how can i add it to question? Do I need to upload it somewhere on internet then copy img link and add it to question.

I see you don't care about the "intersections" in blurred blocks, so then you can apply mask + border-radius to the #top element:


body {
  background-image: url(https://images.pexels.com/photos/33109/fall-autumn-red-season.jpg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=1260&h=750&dpr=1);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}

.rec3 {
  /*Horizontal bar*/
  position: fixed;
  width: 60vw;
  height: 80px;
  backdrop-filter: blur(20px);
  bottom: 20px;
  left: 20px;
  border-radius: 0 25px 25px 80px;
}

.rec4 {
  /*Vertical bar*/
  position: fixed;
  width: 80px;
  height: 60vh;
  bottom: 90px;
  left: 20px;
  backdrop-filter: blur(20px);
  border-radius: 25px 25px 0 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  z-index: -1;
}

#top {
  position: fixed;
  height: 60px;
  width: 60px;
  left: 100px;
  overflow: hidden;
  bottom: 100px;
  backdrop-filter: blur(20px);
  mask: radial-gradient(30px, #0000 99%, #000);
  border-radius: 50% 50% 50% 0;
}
<div class="rec3"></div>
<div class="rec4"></div>
<div id="top"></div>




It worked but this method created circle stroke.
I add blue color to make it easier to see.

It worked when I change 99% to 100%, thanks
